# TypeError when trying to predict labels with argmax

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have successfully followed [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-mobilenet-and-keras-c75daf7ff299) transfer learning tutorial to make my own classifier with two classes, "impressionism" and "modernism".

Now trying to get a label for my test image, applying advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971293/get-class-labels-from-keras-functional-model) thread:

```
y_prob = model.predict(new_image)
y_prob

(gives this output) array([[3.1922062e-04, 9.9968076e-01]], dtype=float32)

y_classes = y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)
y_classes
(gives this output) array([1])

# create a list containing the class labels
labels = ['modernism', 'impressionism']
predicted_label = sorted(labels)[y_classes]
```

Results in error:

```
"TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-571175bcfc65> in <module>()
      1 # create a list containing the class labels
      2 labels = ['modernism', 'impressionism']
----> 3 predicted_label = sorted(labels)[y_classes]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"
```

What am I doing wrong and what would be the right way to access the text labels (and their probabilities) for my test image? If I understand the array prediction, it has recognized from my image folders that there are two classes.

Many thanks if you have time to help!

Comment: can you show the output for what `y_classes` looks like?

Comment: For sure, I just edited the original post! I can paste the whole code if it helps.

Comment: Got it, I've updated my answer below, take a look! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that `y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)` is returning an array value of `[1]`. Only numpy arrays can index/splice with a list.

The issue occurs due to the `sorted` method, I was not accounting for that in my testing. Even though the input array is type `np.ndarray`, the output becomes a list.

So either:

```py
labels = ['modernism', 'impressionism']
predicted_label = numpy.array(sorted(labels))[y_classes]
```

or

```py
labels = numpy.array(['modernism', 'impressionism'])
labels.sort()
predicted_label = labels[y_classes]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I now have `labels = np.array(['modernism', 'impressionism'])
predicted_label = sorted(labels)[y_classes]` but, weirdly enough, I get the same error. Sorted was based on Guillame's advice: "If you have a list of labels called labels, the predicted label name will be: `predicted_label = sorted(labels)[y_classes]`"

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much, I was stuck with this for long. Now I get this output `array(['modernism'], dtype='<U13')`
This is a bit extra, but I wonder if there is a way to print the confidence values? I mean, printing that it is 0.780 sure that it is "modernism" and 0.220 that it is "impressionism". Sorry if the terms are not correct, haha.

Comment: you can do `print(y_prob.max(axis=-1))` and that will print the confidence of the positive class.

Comment: Perfect, this helps a lot! Thanks.